# Adjust space between entries in LoF and LoT

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, tocloft

I am trying to adjust spacing between entries in LoF and LoT. My code is

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=2.8cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength\cftparskip{-15pt}%For ToC works great
\setlength\cftbeforesecskip{-8pt}%For ToC works great
\setlength\cftbeforesubsecskip{-5pt}%For ToC works great
\setlength\cftbeforechapskip{-1pt}%For ToC works great
\setlength\cftaftertoctitleskip{-50pt}%For ToC works great

% I also tried \renewcommand instead of \setlength
\setlength\cftbeforeloftitleskip{-2cm}%It has no effect in LoF
\setlength\cftbeforelottitleskip{-5cm}%It has no effect inLoT

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\tocwithouttitle}{\@starttoc{toc}}
\makeatother
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\lofwithouttitle}{\@starttoc{lof}}
\makeatother
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\lotwithouttitle}{\@starttoc{lot}}
\makeatother
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

\begin{document}

%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Front-Page~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{titlepage}
Εξώφυλλο
\end{titlepage}

\chapter*{\contentsname}
\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\contentsname}}{\MakeUppercase{\contentsname}}
\tocwithouttitle
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Πειρεχόμενα}

%LoF
\chapter*{Κατάλογος σχημάτων}%List of Figures
\markboth{\MakeUppercase{Κατάλογος Σχημάτων}}{\MakeUppercase{Κατάλογος Σχημάτων}}
%\renewcommand\cftbeforeloftitleskip{5pt}
%\renewcommand\cftbeforelottitleskip{5pt}
\lofwithouttitle
%\setlength\cftbeforefigskip{0pt}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Κατάλογος Σχημάτων}

%LoT
\newpage

\chapter*{Κατάλογος Πινάκων}
\markboth{\MakeUppercase{Κατάλογος Πινάκων}}{\MakeUppercase{Κατάλογος Πινάκων}}
\lotwithouttitle
%\renewcommand\cftbeforeloftitleskip{5pt}
%\renewcommand\cftbeforelottitleskip{5pt}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Κατάλογος Πινάκων}

\newpage
\end{document}
```

While some code is working on ToC(See comments in Preamble) I cannot adjust spacing in LoF/LoT. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer!

```
\setlength\cftbeforeloftitleskip{-2cm}
\setlength\cftbeforelottitleskip{-5cm}
```

should be replaced with

```
\setlength\cftbeforefigskip{-2cm}
\setlength\cftbeforetabskip{-5cm}
```

Some good values, just for reference are

```
\setlength\cftbeforefigskip{-5pt}
\setlength\cftbeforetabskip{-5pt}
```