# LOF and LOT: space between entries

Tags: spacing, lists

I have successfully found out how to add space between entries in the list of contents, but how can I make it work with the lists of figures ad tables?

---

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0.5cm, left=2.6cm,right=2.6cm,top=2.6cm,bottom=3cm, footskip=.67cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto\chapter{%
    \ifnum\value{chapter}=0\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip0.1pt}\fi
    }

%\preto\figure{%
%   \ifnum\value{figure}=0\addtocontents{lof}{\vskip10pt}\fi
%}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\begingroup
\let\cleardoublepage\relax
\let\clearpage\relax
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\endgroup

\section{Prologue}
\section{Acknowledgements}
\section{Abstract}
\section{Introduction}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{gfx/no-cloud}
    \caption{There is no cloud}
\end{figure}

\section{Theoretical framework}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{gfx/lb-stick}
    \caption{Libreboot sticker}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{gfx/Trisquel}
    \caption{Fully free GNU/linux}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{gfx/TEX}
    \caption{tex.stackexchange.com}
\end{figure}


\setcounter{table}{0}
\begin{longtable}[H]{c c}
    Q & A  \\
    \hline
    ? & !\\
    \caption{Q\&A}
\end{longtable}


\begin{longtable}[H]{l r}
    1& 2\\
    \caption{Numbers}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}


----------

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0.5cm, left=2.6cm,right=2.6cm,top=2.6cm,bottom=3cm, footskip=.67cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto\chapter{%
    \ifnum\value{chapter}=0\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip0.1pt}\fi
    }

%\preto\figure{%
%   \ifnum\value{figure}=0\addtocontents{lof}{\vskip10pt}\fi
%}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\begingroup
\let\cleardoublepage\relax
\let\clearpage\relax
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\endgroup

\section{Prologue}
\section{Acknowledgements}
\section{Abstract}
\section{Introduction}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{gfx/no-cloud}
    \caption{There is no cloud}
\end{figure}

\section{Theoretical framework}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.7]{gfx/lb-stick}
    \caption{Libreboot sticker}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{gfx/Trisquel}
    \caption{Fully free GNU/linux}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{gfx/TEX}
    \caption{tex.stackexchange.com}
\end{figure}


\setcounter{table}{0}
\begin{longtable}[H]{c c}
    Q & A  \\
    \hline
    ? & !\\
    \caption{Q\&A}
\end{longtable}


\begin{longtable}[H]{l r}
    1& 2\\
    \caption{Numbers}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

---

[image: lb.stick.png]
[image: no-cloud.png]
[image: TEX.png]
[image: Trisquel.png]

Comment: Are you referring to the vertical or horizontal spacing?

Comment: Sorry for my imprecision: vertical spacing.

Comment: @egreg: I can see, that you edited my code. Thanks for the efforts. What did I do wrong, and what should I do next time?

Comment: @jbahn For inserting code, type or paste it in; then select it and click the `{}` icon above the editing box (or hit Control-K).

Comment: @egreg: OK, I think I got it. Sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for the help.

Comment: @jbahn: You can use [`tocloft`](//ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) with `\setlength{\cftaftertoctitleskip}{\dimexpr\cftaftertoctitleskip-A}
\setlength{\cftafterloftitleskip}{\dimexpr\cftafterloftitleskip-B}
\setlength{\cftafterlottitleskip}{\dimexpr\cftafterlottitleskip-C}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{A}
\setlength{\cftbeforefigskip}{B}
\setlength{\cftbeforetabskip}{C}` where you select `A`, `B` and `C` (preferably the same).

Comment: @Werner: What does A, B and C resemble? Would I have to make a line for each entry in lof and lot?

Comment: @Werner: Can you guide my to the question this is a duplicate of? I can't find it.

Comment: @jbahn: `A`, `B` and `C` are lengths. You can add the code in your preamble just after `\usepackage{tocloft}` is also added. The [duplicate post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79396/5764) is added to the top of your original post.

Comment: @Werner: Thanks. My actual preamble is much longer and when I include tocloft, I get a list of errors. Should I include those in my original question or make a new, in which I include everything? Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @Werner: If I use tocloft I get this error: <Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 668.> Line 668 says: <\addtocontents{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\noindent {}Articles:}{}}> and is used to add an entry to the LOC  indicating a list of articles

Comment: @jbahn: It would be better if you post your entire code so one can see what's going on. Consider using [Pastebin](//pastebin.com) and post a link here.

Comment: @Werner. Thanks. I think there is something wrong with this line (668). Can you help me check it?: \addtocontents{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\noindent {}Articles:}{}}

Comment: @Werner: I seem to have solved the problem with line 668. Following advise from here <http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=20307>, I changed it in to     \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Articles:} which allows me to use tocloft. Next step is trying your advise on the vertical space.

Comment: @Werner: I got it to wok. Thanks a lot. I must say though that it took quite some time and investigation to figure out that <\dimexpr\cftafterloftitles‌​kip-B> just means: enter a length! Anyway, thanks a lot for your efforts.

Comment: @Werner: Can I not mark my question as solved and your answer as helpful?

Comment: @jbahn: No. You can vote on the duplicate question and it's answers.

Comment: @jbahn: `\dimexpr\cftafterloftitleskip-B` removes `B` from the default `\cftafterloftitleskip`, since it will be added by every entry within the LoF. Otherwise you'll have all of the entries starting lower than usual. You don't have to use it.

Comment: Only that did not help me. Your advised here did.